# Which filesystem is required to move PS3 save data to USB harddrive?

Tags: ps3, hard-drive

The Blu-ray drive on my very old PS3 is broken, so I bought another one. I want to transfer my save data from the old one to the new one (and only them). I have a USB harddrive which I normally use for my PS4. I formatted it with `exfat` filesystem. It seems PS3 does not recognize it, although the harddrive is okay.

Which filesystem is required? Is really only `vfat` possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PS3 only recognizes USB drives formatted in FAT32.

Comment: Because its OS is Linux-based.

Comment: Linux can exfat and ntfs. I use debian

Comment: @phoss3010 I transfered the data over ether,; i found my ether cable.  thanks.